# .NET Core load correct configs based on publishing profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, app-config, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm hosting a .NET Core 2.0 application as a service using [PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService](https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService) nugget, it all works fine so far.

My problem is that this service will have multiple instances on the same server running different things based on config files.

Why not make the same service do both, you might ask. Because I only have 1 Development server for all services and there is 1 server per site in Production, so it has to be split.

Example:

- Instance 1 of service runs a file eraser for site US;
- Instance 2 of service runs a file eraser for site CA;

Instance 1 should load "appsettings.US.json" and instance 2 "appsettings.CA.json". "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Environment variable is not a solution because it's global and would affect both services (in the Development server). I currently have this to run in localy:

```
string environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Both sites are also in the same Development server, but it's fine because it was a Web.config setting the variable in IIS for each specific site. I wonder if there is something similar for services, because it would be a great solution for my problem, but I've been banging my head on the wall and found nothing.

Other possible solution would be to publish only the correct config, then rename it so that "appsettings.US.json" would just be called "appsettings.json" and I would load that only instead, but all my attempts at this have failed, it appears to not be respecting the publishing profile and just does what I set on the file properties (copy to output option).

Am I possibly doing anything wrong in the publishing profiles, is there any "Environment variable" server specific type of thing, or is there even any other solution that I'm not remembering?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [command-line configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#commandline-configuration-provider)? Then, you can specify whatever custom setting(s) you need as start parameters when you set up the service.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args);
```

I would stick with leaving `appsettings.{environment}.json` dedicated to traditional environments, like "Development", "Staging", "Production", etc. You can add sections to your settings, then, for each country (?) like:

```
{
    ...
    "Countries": {
        "US": {
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        "CA": {
            "foo": "baz"
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you customize these settings based on development/production, should you need to. Then, create class like:

```
public class CountryConfig
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
var country = Configuration.Get<string>("country");
services.AddSingleton(Configuration.GetSection($"Countries.{country}").Get<CountryConfig>());
```

Set the following as your startup parameters for the service:

```
country=US
```

And, then finally, just inject `CountryConfig` where you need it.

Comment: That's actually a great solution, just wondering if there is nothing config based. If nothing shows up I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Apparently PeterKottas's nugget doesn't currently allow this solution, but already created an issue on github (https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService/issues/50), until then, this answer won't help me